# show the inputed email in the next page above the password field in

Tags: html, css, authentication, input, passwords

I am creatig a login system. I want the user to input the email and then click next. Then the user will be redirected to the password input page. I want to put he email that the user has typed above the password field.

Do someone know how to do it?

Comment: Do you check the emailaddress after clicking Next, before showing the next screen. If not, why using this method?

Comment: Better Share Your code also.

Comment: please share your code, share more detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use forms to do this, but really we try not to use forms anymore. A more modern way is to use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Also, you cannot do this with just HTML and CSS. You need to use javascript also.

Here is an example of how it might work.

#### PAGE ONE:

```
<label for="emlInput">Email: </label>
<input type="email" id="emlInput" />
<button id="btnNext">Next</button>

<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        const btnNext = document.getElementById('btnNext');
        btnNext.addEventListener("click", advancePage, false);
    });

    function advancePage() {
        const elEml = document.getElementById('emlInput');
        localStorage.setItem('eml', elEml.value);
        window.location.href = "t2.html";
    }
</script>
```

#### PAGE2

```
<div>
    <h2>Password For: <span id="emlSpan"></span></h2>
</div>
<label for="pwd">Password: </label>
<input type="password" id="pwd" />

<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        const ls = localStorage.getItem('eml');
        const eml = document.getElementById('emlSpan');
        eml.innerText = ls;
    });
</script>
```