# How can I make a Dynamic Form Based on Names and Length of Array?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following script taken from stackoverflow. It generates a number of input fields based on a number entered by the user. The problem is I need it to generate a number of input fields based the length of an array [loren, ipsum, plumpus, dumbas], and assign names to the fields that correspond to the strings in the array.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function addFields(){
            // Number of inputs to create
            var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
            // Container <div> where dynamic content will be placed
            var container = document.getElementById("container");
            // Clear previous contents of the container
            while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
                container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
            }
            for (i=0;i<number;i++){
                // Append a node with a random text
                container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Member " + (i+1)));
                // Create an <input> element, set its type and name attributes
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "text";
                input.name = "member" + i;
                container.appendChild(input);
                // Append a line break 
                container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="">Number of members: (max. 10)<br />
    <a href="#" id="filldetails" onclick="addFields()">Fill Details</a>
    <div id="container"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297143/dynamically-create-a-html-form-with-javascript

Comment: Are you looking for four input fields with name from this array? `[loren, ipsum, plumpus, dumbas]`
Then what will happen to the user input?

Comment: Correct. I ultimately want to save the user input in another array or perhaps a tuple. I shall comment on your perfect response below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started. Below example allows you to type several words into the input field (Members), separated by commas, and create that many fields.

These lines take the text in the input field and create an array from the values (requires the values be separated by commas).

```
var arr = input.split(',');
var number = arr.length;
```

Then in your loop, use this line to add the desired array element where it is needed. I placed it in the input field's value (content), but you could easily move it outside the field to be the label, or use `input.id = arr[i]` to set the id for the field definition.

```js
function addFields(){
 // Number of inputs to create
 var input = document.getElementById("member").value;
 var arr = input.split(',');
 var number = arr.length;
 // Container <div> where dynamic content will be placed
 var container = document.getElementById("container");
 // Clear previous contents of the container
 while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
   container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
 }
 for (i=0;i<number;i++){
   // Append a node with a random text
   container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Member " + (i+1)));
   // Create an <input> element, set its type and name attributes
   var input = document.createElement("input");
   input.type = "text";
   input.name = "member" + i;
   input.value = arr[i];
   container.appendChild(input);
   // Append a line break 
   container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
 }
}
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="lorem, ipsum, plumpus, dumbas"> Members: (max. 10)<br />
    <a href="#" id="filldetails" onclick="addFields()">Fill Details</a>
    <div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: @W.Lyman I suggest that you reconsider your accepted answer. Notice that in the accepted answer the four values are hard-coded. Any need to use different values will require changing the underlying javascript. The above example creates the underlying array from values typed into the input field. **To save the values and read them from a separate document, see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59521218/show-the-inputed-email-in-the-next-page-above-the-password-field-in/59521627#59521627)** Please remember to upvote.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it ins't exactly what I was trying to do. I apologize if my question wasn't clear, I'm just beginning to use stackoverflow. I thought that Sifat Haque's was closest to what I was trying to achieve, but looking at your answer again, I see that yours contains all the components of what I needed and some additional pointers. I will reconsider my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = ['Mark', 'Erik', 'Dave'];
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Maybe this helps

Answer (score 1):

```js
const dummyArray = [{
    fieldLabel: "Lorem",
    fieldName: "lorem"
  },
  {
    fieldLabel: "Ipsum",
    fieldName: "ipsum"
  },
  {
    fieldLabel: "Dolor",
    fieldName: "dolor"
  },
  {
    fieldLabel: "Sit",
    fieldName: "sit"
  },
]

function generateFields() {
// Reset "container"
  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = ""
  dummyArray.forEach(item => {
    // Get label from array
    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.fieldLabel));
    // Create an <input> element, set its type and name attributes
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    // Get input name from array
    input.name = item.fieldName;
    container.appendChild(input);
    // Append a line break 
    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  })
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="filldetails" onclick="generateFields()">Generate Fields</a>
<div id="container" />
```

Comment: I am very impressed at how perfectly and quickly you all responded. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create your input fields using the array `[loren, ipsum, plumpus, dumbas]` then here is the modified version of your code to do that.

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"/>


    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function addFields(){
        var fieldNames = ['loren', 'ipsum', 'plumpus', 'dumbas'];
            // Container <div> where dynamic content will be placed
            var container = document.getElementById("container");
            // Clear previous contents of the container
            while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
                container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
            }
            
            for (i=0;i<fieldNames.length;i++){
                // Append a node with a random text
                container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fieldNames[i]));
                // Create an <input> element, set its type and name attributes
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "text";
                input.name = fieldNames[i];
                container.appendChild(input);
                // Append a line break 
                container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            }
        }
        addFields();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: perfect. bless you. I ultimately want to save the input values so that I can find ['loren', 'ipsum', 'plumpus', 'dumbas'] in a separate document and replace them with the new input values! any idea how to do that within the same script?